# The loop is only activated once Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I created job:

[image]

I read all files in directory and i writing to file txt: filename.txt
[image]

Next I  have transformation where I read filename.txt and copy rows to result

[image]

In last transformation I read data from step: Get rows from result and I passing to Job Executor

[image]

In log I see that step: Get rows from result read all rows:

```
Get rows from result.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=4, W=4, U=0, E=0)
```

And my job executor where I have shell script:

[image]

My script:

```
    D:
cd D:\Kafka\prep
rename %FILENAME% RENAME_%FILENAME%
```

Unfortunately the loop, although step: Get rows from result read 4 rows then the loop is executed only once.
My all project is here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oABWKODX7NaM8hfa1TwCSmImPMLtP-ov?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you made enabled execute for every row option?

Answer (score 0):

In your transformation 2, you have send 10 rows per group. Where you need to send 1 by 1 row. Thus you need update this value from 10 to 1.
[image]

Comment: it looks like the script has been executed the correct number of times, but all the time for the same argument: